# Angular update variable value when form input is changed

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular and i have a generated model that needs to get the compute the age when the user inserts the age, i am doing it with Reactive forms with the following code (reused the generated component name-editor for testing purpouses):
In components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-editor',
  templateUrl: './name-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name-editor.component.css']
})
export class NameEditorComponent {
  name = new FormControl(new Date());
  age = new Date().getFullYear() - (this.name.value as Date).getFullYear();
  check = (this.name.value as Date).getFullYear();
}
```

In component.html:

```
<form>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" type="date" [formControl]="name" [ng]>
    <p>Value: {{ name.value }}</p>
    <p>Age: {{ age}}</p>
    <p>{{check}}</p>
</form>
```

The result is:
[image], as you can see the value is changed and detected, but age and check does not change, how i can get the updated value of both elements?

Comment: You can use [`ngDoCheck()`](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck) to update the values of `age` and `check` when name changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is subscribe to `name.valueChanges`. First you would start by adding this `ngIf` to the html:

```html
<form *ngIf="{n:name$|async}">
```

Then you would just watch for changes on `name.valueChanges` from the `FormControl` and apply the updates you would like through `tap`:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  name = new FormControl(new Date());
  age = this.getAge();
  check = this.getCheck();

  // Watches for changes on name and when a change happens
  // both age and check will be re-calculated
  name$ = this.name.valueChanges.pipe(
    tap(() => this.age = this.getAge()),
    tap(() => this.check = this.getCheck())
  );

  getAge() {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.getCheck();
  }

  getCheck() {
    return new Date(this.name.value).getFullYear();
  }
}
```

This option is good because it only executes when the value on name gets changed, whereas the next option (see below) executes whenever any property changes.

---

Another option is to use `ngDoCheck()` which will run a check whenever angular runs it's change hook(s) on a bound property change.

```js
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck {
  // These are bound to the template, so they will cause
  // change detection to run when they get updated
  name = new FormControl(new Date());
  age = this.getAge();
  check = this.getCheck();

  // Runs when bound properties are changed
  ngDoCheck() {
    this.age = this.getAge();
    this.check = this.getCheck();
  }

  getAge() {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.getCheck();
  }

  getCheck() {
    return new Date(this.name.value).getFullYear();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the first option as you said is more specific: two things i have to add: it is necessary to import `import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';` and change the last line to `return new Date(this.name.value as Date).getFullYear();`